# Map function doesn't iterate all children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am building a sidebar for an app, which consists of smaller elements. Right now stuck with an issue where sidebar child element array isn't fully iterated although each child element consists of an unique key. I have a feeling that it might be related to key. :/

**Sidebar element component:**

```
var AppSidebar = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      children: []
    };
  },

  getPlaylists: function() {
    var that = this;

    // returns array of objects
    spotify.getMePlaylists(function(err, playlists) {
      if(err)
        console.error(err);

      that.setState({
        children: playlists
      });
    });

  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.getPlaylists();
  },

  render: function() {

    // iterates all children
    this.state.children.map(function(playlist) {
      console.log(1, playlist.id, playlist.name);
    });

    var playlists = this.state.children;

    return (
      <div id="sidebar">
        playlists.map(function(playlist) {
          // only returns first playlist id and name
          console.log(2, playlist.id, playlist.name);
          return (<AppSidebarElement key={playlist.id} {...playlist} />);
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**Sidebar component:**

```
var AppSidebarElement = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="playlist">
        {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**Console output:**

```
1 "75dwLdmL07hDEDWqX17QeE" "The Indie Mix"
1 "2wOXCZ6fJAjpekKlnbg49F" "Interesting artists"
1 "6ULfvJbsdzF7u14dBZo9w1" "chsshhh"
1 "4LJ5hkgqt04IKw454SUJqV" "Motivational Songs"
1 "75if3ukZz2tPS60IVMPhw6" "Best of the Suits Soundtrack"
...

2 "69H6RgTVs1jrv1IuuLe1a5" "Deep Dark Indie"
```

Comment: Have you checked that the length of `playlists` is what you expect?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine until i do playlist iteration and child element creationg, it only iterates the first element but doesn't return even the single child. AppSidebar DOM is empty :/

I find this wierd, because in a different project did the same, but never had issue like this :/ tried comparing code

Comment: do you see any error if you wrap the `return (<AppSidebarElement key={playlist.id} {...playlist} />);` with a `try { ... } catch (e) {console.log(e)}` ?

Comment: Nope, nothing outputed

Comment: didn't you forget a `{` before `playlists.map`  in AppSidebar's render function ?

Comment: Damn that helped, but found out that `(<AppSidebarElement key={playlist.id} {...playlist} />);` returns nothing due to the spread attribute `{...playlist}` which is an Object class instance :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by code which i cleaned up while posting it to stack-overflow, it was related to calling wrong `this` within map function context.